# Optical tweezers : dipole force or radiative pressure?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, dipole, laser-interaction

Two types of forces are usually considered to describe light-matter interaction. On the one hand, the radiative pressure, which corresponds to absorption - spontaneous emission cycles, is proportional to the gradient of the phase of the em-field. On the other hand, the dipole force, which corresponds to absorption - stimulated emission cycles, is proportional to the gradient of the intensity of the em-field. The former depends on the dissipative part of susceptibility, the latter on the reactive part.

While reading about optical tweezers, I came with (seemingly) contradictory interpretations. People claim the trapping potential results from the dipole force, bringing the trapped particle in high-intensities regions, but then perform a calculation simply based on momentum conservation, arguing this force applied by the light on the particle is due to the radiative pressure excerpt by deviated photons.

So now I'm confused. How come two forces, resulting from two different phenomena, are considered as one and the same in this situation ?